# Android save a list of custom objects

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating an app that has a sort of Master-Detail `ListView` of custom objects. My `Adapter` is an array of custom objects:

```
ArrayAdapter<Record> adapter;
```

which is being added to a `ListView` dynamically. I need to preserve the list, so that when the user opens the app again the list is how it was when they closed it. I looked into using `SharedPreferences` since that is what I'm using for the settings of my app but I can't figure out how to save a list of my custom objects with it. After reading documentation it seems like `SharedPreferences` is just for simple key-value pairs. Does anyone know how I can save this list? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Example: 
Writing:

```
List<Record> records;
ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(context.openFileOutput("records.dat",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
stream.writeObject(list);
stream.close();
```

Example: Reading:

```
       ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(context.openFileInput("records.dat"));
  records = (List<Records)inputStream.readObject();
  inputStream.close();
```

just make sure the classes your are using are [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: `writeObject` is not a method of `FileOutputStream`, do I need to use `ObjectOutputStream` instead?